# Why is linear functional F continuous with respect to the sup norm, not l2 norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $-\infty <a<c<b <\infty $. Let linear functional F(x)=x(c), $x\in C[a, b]$.
Why is F continuous with respect to the sup norm, not l2 norm?
Why does it not make sense to define functional G on $L^2[a, b]$ by G(x)=x(c)?

Comment: To answer your second question, functions are only identified almost everywhere in $L^2[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toward your first question, we see $$\lvert F(x)\rvert = \lvert x(c) \rvert \le \| x \|_{\infty}$$ which shows that $F$ is bounded (equivalently continuous) with respect to the sup norm with bound at most $1$. [Recall that the operator norm is the smallest number $C \ge 0$ satisfying $\lvert F(x) \rvert \le C \| x \|_\infty$ for all $x \in C[a,b]$.]

With the $L^2$ norm on $C[a,b]$ , for $n$ large enough, we can define $$x^2_n(t) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 0, & a \le t < c - 1/n, \\ 
n^2(t - [c - 1/n]), & c - 1/n \le t < c, \\
n^2(c + 1/n - t), & c \le t \le c + 1/n,\\
0, & c +1/n < t \le b.
 \end{matrix} \right.$$ We see $F(x_n) = x_n(c) = \sqrt n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. However, each $ x_n^2$ is a spike of height $n$ and base $2/n$ and so $$\| x_n \|_{L^2} = 2, \,\,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$$ If $F$ was continuous, there would be $C \ge 0$ so that $$F(x_n) \le C \| x_n \|_{L^2} \,\,\, \Longleftrightarrow \,\,\, \sqrt n \le 2C \,\,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$$ This, of course, is impossible. Hence $F$ is not bounded with respect to the $L^2$ norm on $C[a,b]$. As a general rule, any operator that depends on pointwise values of $x(t)$ will be continuous in the supremum notm but not in any of the $L^p$ norms for a similar reason.

We can't define the operator on $L^2[a,b]$ because $L^2$ functions are not defined pointwise. They are equivalence classes of function which are equal almost everywhere and so the operator wouldn't be well-defined. For example, the functions $$x(t) = 0 \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, y(t) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 0, & t \neq c \\ 
1, & t = c\\
 \end{matrix} \right.$$ are equal in $L^2[a,b]$ but the functional would send them to different values; hence it isn't well defined (a map can have only one output for a given input).